# Where Hibernate search store index

Tags: windows, hibernate, ubuntu, lucene, hibernate-search

I would like to run one project on Windows and Ubuntu, with the same properties.

Hibernate Search create index in this dir:

```
<property name="hibernate.search.default.indexBase" value="/Users/path"/>
```

On Windows this path resolves to D:\Users\path

On Ubuntu i can not run project because no permission for writting indexex. I want to give such permission to directories but i don't know where Hibernate wants to create this directories.
How Ubuntu resolve that path?

Comment: Ubuntu resolves that path literally as `/Users/path`.

Answer (score 0):

You'll have to use a different value on Ubuntu than the one you use on Windows.

If you need the configuration files to be the same, you can omit this property, and pass it to the JVM as a system property instead.

Hibernate always looks for matching system properties and/or environment variables, on top of its configuration files.